# Finding Dropbox directory ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dropbox

I have a dropbox account which sync all my website folders. and it works well on windows using my apache to test, because apache can find the directory. I have another development computer using Ubuntu 13, and i changed the document root in apache to /home/jacques/dropbox but it cant find the directory , so i opened my home folder. i saw the directory there, so i tried to access it using the terminal, it said that the directory doesnt exist.
I did right click dropbox and that said that the directory is in /home/dropbox and /home/jacques/dropbox

am i missing something important here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to check here -

1. First is that on Ubuntu the default Dropbox directory is
   /home/username/Dropbox not /home/username/dropbox. Note the capital
   'D', linux file systems are case-sensitive. Make sure that you specify it with the capital D in the DocumentRoot declaration.
2. The second is to check what user Apache is running as and making
   sure that it has permissions to view your Dropbox directory. On
   Ubuntu, the default is www-data, so you might want to add yourself
   to the www-data group and change the group on the Dropbox folder to
   be www-data.

   Alternatively, you can change the user and group that Apache runs as by editing  the                     /etc/apache2/envvars file and by making
   these edits:

   ```
   export APACHE_RUN_USER=jacques
   export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=jacques
   ```

   You will need to restart Apache after this, and you may need to update the owner of the /var/log/apache2 directory to be you also.